# Is it possible to address localhost from linux ubuntu to a virtualbox virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I'm working on Linux ubuntu, so to test the page on IE6/7/8 etc I run a virtual machine using virtual box; I also need to see how my localhost looks on IE in a windows virtual box environment).

but I dont want to re install my poroject on, lamp on the vm

In my real machine, I open the website simply using the URL local, how do I address this localhost from my Linux ubuntu to the virtual machine?

Right now my workaround is to use the IP address. Any better ideas?

Comment: So you want to see the content of a website located in your virtual box? I think the good solution is to use the IP, yes. Otherwise you can also add the IP to your `/etc/hosts` file so that you can alias it.

Comment: the website is located on the linux ubuntu. i want to view it on my virtual box. without installing zend, lamp or xampp on my virtual box

Comment: OK so it is the other way round from what I said. Anyway, one solution can be the same: add the IP to your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Exactly. can you give me an example on how do I rewrite that on my host file.

Comment: With root user edit it and add a line like `192.168.2.1  my_machine`

Answer (score 2):

In the default network configuration (NAT) for VirtualBox you can accesss the host machine with the IP `10.0.2.2`, so in the browser you would use that instead of `localhost`. (I can't find this in the official documentation though?)